# bash check value is integer and in range

Tags: variables, integer, busybox

I read this stackoverflow question...

[Bash: check user input is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848342/bash-check-user-input-is-correct)

which does most of what I want however rather then checking it's just an integer I need to check it's an integer in a variable range....

The script looks for files in a directory and then assigns a number to them...

1. File 1
2. File 2
3. File 3
   etc....

The user chooses the the number and the script then executes commands against that file.....the variable $FILELIST is the total number of files.

Taking the example from the previous stackoverflow I tried.....

```
FILENUM=""
while [[ ! ($FILENUM =~ ^[0-$FILELIST]+$) ]]; do
    echo " "
    echo "Please enter the file number: "
    read -p "1 - $FILELIST" FILENUM < /dev/tty
done

echo "$FILENUM"
```

However this is throwing a syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "do") in the while line and I'm not sure why, I suspect $FILELIST has to be bracketed somehow but an explanation as to why the above works would help me understand the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I should add this is in a busybox shell so that may be the problem?

Comment: Hmm, as a first comment, the regex `^[0-$FILELIST]+$` is probably not what you want. Say `$FILELIST` is 100, then the regex is `^[0-100]+$` which will only match numbers with 0s and 1s in them, as opposed to numbers between 0 and 100...

Comment: I tried changing the line to test for a 0-9 variable (replacing $FILELIST with 9) and it throws the same error, so I'm starting to think maybe this is a busybox limitation?

Comment: Thanks M.C but the filelist will never be more then 9 so no problem there, I'm really trying to understand why the error is getting thrown to help my coding for the future rather then just following someone else's example.

Comment: I don't know much about Busybox, but [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) says it uses the **ash** shell not **bash**, so you may need to re-tag your question and look up some ash syntax (again I can't help you here)

Answer (score 1):

bash-specific answers:

You don't need to reinvent the wheel: use the `select` builtin:

```
cd /path/to/directory
PS3="Select a file: "
select file in *; do
    if [[ $file ]]; then break; fi
done
echo "You selected '$file'"
echo "You selected file number $REPLY"
```

To check a number is within a certain range, I'd write:

```
if (( 0 <= $number && $number <= $max )); then echo "in range"; fi
```

---

Since you're using ash you might use this as a reference: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dash

```
while true; do
    FILENUM=""
    echo 
    echo "Please enter the file number: "
    read -p "1 - $FILELIST" FILENUM < /dev/tty
    if expr "$FILENUM" : '[0-9]\+$' &&
       [ $FILENUM -gt 0 ] && 
       [ $FILENUM -le $FILELIST ]
    then
        break
    fi
done
echo "$FILENUM"
```

Comment: Unfortunately select isn't part of the busybox buitins.  http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html