# Accept only input in a certain range in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a quick bash script and I only want to accept integers in between 0-9 as input. I've looked but haven't found much so apologies if the answer exists somewhere. I'll delete the post if another has the answer.
Thank you

Comment: The first Google result for `bash read and check input` gives http://stackoverflow.com/q/848342/7010554. Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ 1 ]] ; do
    echo -n "Enter a number: "
    read input
    if [[ "$input" =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] ; then
        break
    fi
done

echo "Got $input"
```

Note that this option requires a bash that supports regular expressions.  Also, it explicitly allows only a single integer, as you appeared to be requesting in your question.

Comment: Perfect thanks @eddiem!

Comment: You don't need regular expressions to do this - glob patterns with `[[ $input == [0-9] ]]` would suffice.